# Fetch Cloud composer logs and print that log in email body

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to fetch logs dynamically from google cloud composer(airflow also) with different severity level and want that error log to be printed in email body.
I followed up with this link - https://www.syntio.net/en/labs-musings/write-error-logs-from-composer-and-create-an-alert-policy-on-stackdriver , but stuck while printing log in email and it returned "None".
Please help me out.

[Snapshot of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT4Nv.jpg)

Note: PubSub might not be in picture. Though the DAG is triggered uploading a file in input bucket. It's been selected as finalize/create for cloud function.

Comment: Logs are generated on a GCS Bucket, maybe you can use event-driven architecture and listen to [GCS notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)

Comment: @vdolez Though I am new to GCP and airflow, it will be okay if you elaborate it. And how can we fetch the log from GCS bucket? Another question! Is it possible to fetch logs from airflow?

Comment: Logs are created in a [dedicated Ccomposer folder](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage), you can then treat them as they come in a Cloud Function.

Comment: @vdolez Okay let me try that. And will let you know.  Because for the trigger, a file to be uploaded in input bucket. And in cloud function, this trigger is been selected as finalize/create.